# Cloudflare Api v4 php Curl -error Method POST not available for that URI

Tags: php, api, curl, cloudflare

I am noob at coding and using apis. 
I am using this code to edit rocketloader option via cloudflare api.

```html
<?php

$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
                 'X-Auth-Email: <email>',
                 'X-Auth-Key: <key>',
                 'Content-Type: application/json',
                  );
$data = array(
              'value' => 'on',
               );
$json = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/<zone id>/settings/rocket_loader");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

?>
```

It shows this error.

```html
   Method POST not available for that URI.
```

What is wrong with the code? Can you help me?

Comment: did you replace `<zone id>`, `<email>` and `<key>` with your credentials?

Comment: yes i did it. creating zones and adding dns records are working fine, but others. exmple this one: rocketloader option doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CloudFlare API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-settings-change-rocket-loader-setting), the endpoint you are trying to reach should be a `PATCH` request, you are accessing it with a `POST` request as you are using `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`. Try adding the following right before `curl_exec`:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$data = array('value' => on);
```

Remove quotes!